# how to add rows in rich:datatable using javascript in richfaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces

I wanted to know if there is any way to generate new `rich:datatable` rows using JavaScript.
I already made a link to generate row dynamically. In HTML it look like

`onclick=”RichFaces.ajax.request("Form_PageData_Container:remappedTable:0:remappedTableAddRow",event,{"incId":"1"} );return false;”`

How can I call this within JavaScript to add rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use `a4j:jsFunction`, e.g.

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="addTableRow" action="#{bean.addTableRow)" render="table" />
```

then you can simply call `addTableRow()` from JavaScript.